# Need some experienced eyes on removing cog/rear wheel mechanism

Tags: sprocket, rear-wheel

I've looked all over the net and can't find the proper tool or D.I.Y tool to take this apart. It's a single speed (with a ratcheting mechanism), and I'm trying to take it apart to make it a fixie.

In the inner ring thingy, I counted 9 splines, and on that outer ring I counted 6 grooves. I compared all of this to park tool pictures, but did not find anything fitting.

[image]

Home solutions and advice are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outer ring looks like a lock ring. [This](http://www.parktool.com/product/fixed-gear-lockring-wrench-hcw-17) should help you get it off:
[image]

Comment: Or a small cold chisel and a few taps with a hammer.

Answer (score 1):

As a "home solution" for a lockring wrench, I've seen photos of people taking a large pair of waterpump pliars, ( buy a cheap pair with the proper jaw width ), and then grinding out a "slot" just back of the tips of the jaws so the tips would fit down into the "U" shaped cutouts and serve as a lockring tool to remove the outer ring from the cog.